# USB-to-Ethernet adapter and plugged into Pi's ethernet port & laptop's USB port?

Tags: usb, ssh, wireless, ethernet

Is it possible to plug a USB-to-Ethernet adapter into a Raspberry Pi's Ethernet port and the USB end into a laptop's USB cord to immediately share Internet connection with the Pi? My laptops don't have Ethernet ports and I'd like to `ssh` into `raspberrypi.local` without the Pi having to be set up to connect to the same network as the laptop. Plus, I'd like if I don't need to set up any configuration to share the connection (So I could `ssh` into the Pi right upon plugging it into a laptop.).

I was thinking of an adapter like this with an Ethernet cable plugged into the port on the adapter:

[image]

Comment: You provide minimal information - like what OS is on your laptop. NOTE You can have ICS **OR** `ssh` access to the Pi, **NOT BOTH**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work. You need 1 ethernet port on your Raspberry Pi and 1 ethernet port on your PC to connect your Raspberry Pi to your laptop. You can use a USB to ethernet cord when you don't have an ethernet port available.

- If you have a Raspberry Pi 3 B and a laptop with an available ethernet port, just connect those with an ethernet cord, no need for USB to ethernet cords.
- If you have a Raspberry Pi without an ethernet port and a laptop with an available ethernet port, you need 1 USB to ethernet cord for the Raspberry Pi.
- If you have a Raspberry Pi without an ethernet port and a laptop without an available ethernet port, you need 2 USB to ethernet cords, 1 for the Raspberry Pi and 1 for the laptop.

To set up SSH on a fresh install of Raspbian:

- Use a keyboard and display, run `sudo raspi-config` and set up SSH from there.
- Alternative method (when you have no keyboard or display): make a file called `ssh` in the `/boot/` directory of Raspbian before you boot your Raspberry Pi.

I should also mention that some people are using [SSH over USB](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=791) for the Raspberry Pi **Zero** (without using WiFi or ethernet). This is done by enabling "gadget mode" on the Raspberry Pi **Zero**, allowing the Raspberry Pi **Zero** to become both host/slave over USB.

Comment: Are there any USB-to-Ethernet adapters for the laptop? I am planning to use this as a portable Linux system with internet...

Comment: Ofcourse there are, you even posted a picture of one in your question.

Comment: Would I need 2?

Comment: I edited my question. It depends on your available network ports.

Answer (score 0):

That should work granted you don't need internet, like the other answer above you need to enable ssh. If using the raspberry pi imager you can setup a domain and enable ssh without ever stepping foot in the Raspberry Pi os. Keep in mind that you will need to download Apple's Bonjour print service, and that if you want to use a command like:

```
sudo apt update
```

You will need an internet connection. If you are using Windows you can go into your network adapter settings, then go into the settings for your wifi adapter, then select share network connection and choose the USB Ethernet port. You should now have internet on your raspberry pi while being directly connected to your computer.